# Terminals and co-terminals for angles

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I'm trying to understand how my teacher converted these angles. I'm not sure if my title is correct but I'm assuming that's what he was doing.

For a unit circle he had, 
\begin{align*}
u & = \left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right), \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\right)\\
  & = \left(-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right), \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right)
\end{align*}

How did he move from line 1 to 2, what is it called? Refer me to a youtube video or some other source for better understanding please?

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, well, those two ordered pairs are not equal, so either your teacher made a mistake or you copied something down wrong.

Note that $$\Bigl(\cos\frac{2\pi}{3} , \sin\frac{2\pi}{3}\Bigr)=\Bigl(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Bigr)$$ whereas $$\Bigl(-\cos\frac{\pi}{6} , \sin\frac{\pi}{6}\Bigr)=\Bigl(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)\,.$$ Obviously these are not the same. Also, it's also not clear what your teacher might have meant, since $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ is coterminal with $-\frac{4\pi}{3}$, while $\frac{\pi}{6}$ is coterminal with $-\frac{11\pi}{6}$...

EDIT: Perhaps it is worth noting that $$\Bigl(\cos\frac{2\pi}{3} , \sin\frac{2\pi}{3}\Bigr)=\Bigl(-\sin\frac{\pi}{6} , -\cos\frac{\pi}{6}\Bigr)\,.$$

Comment: Thank you. I'll definitely consult him about that.